# Editing SQLite Database is not working in my app

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an app which just stores, displays, edits and deletes a persons details. I am still new to android, My app can store, display and delete data. But the edit is not working. I have messed up the code, When I edit, the Persons just name is changed only in home page, and when I click on a particular item, It opens a new Activity called PersonDetails, here the details about that person should have been changed, but they stay the same as before. Could someone please help me out? I have been scratching my brain about this for 2 days

Here's my repository
https://github.com/fayazara/Accounts

Comment: Please share the relevant erroneous here rather than linking to your complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `DBAdapter.java` :

Replace:

```
//Update a person
public void updateContact(long rowId, Person p){
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_NAME, p.getName());
    args.put(KEY_PHONE, p.getPhone());
    args.put(KEY_ACCOUNT, p.getAccount());
    args.put(KEY_BANK, p.getBank());
    args.put(KEY_BANK_IFSC, p.getBankIfsc());
}
```

With:

```
    //Update a person
    public boolean updateContact(long rowId, Person p){
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_NAME, p.getName());
        args.put(KEY_PHONE, p.getPhone());
        args.put(KEY_ACCOUNT, p.getAccount());
        args.put(KEY_BANK, p.getBank());
        args.put(KEY_BANK_IFSC, p.getBankIfsc());
        String where = KEY_NAME + "= '" + p.getName() + "'";
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, where, null) != 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, That was a quick reply! It worked. Cant believe I missed the where clause. Could you please also tell me why is it returning a boolean?

Comment: Glad it helped. Check this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])